# Having Trouble Reading Params in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a project that has the following models:

```
storyboards has many frames
frames has one of each puzzles and scenes
scenes
puzzles
```

I have it set so that frames exist in association with a storyboard, however i have both puzzles and scenes existing separately.  I want to create both scenes and puzzles separately, and then assign them to a frame when a frame is created.  In the new form for frames, I have two collections, one for puzzles and one for scenes.  I want to be able to take the selected item, look up that item, and save a reference to the frame number in the appropriate scene/puzzle table.  However, I keep getting a blank parameter.
My controller code is as follows:

```
class FramesController < ApplicationController

before_action :set_storyboard
before_action :set_frame, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def new
    @frame = @storyboard.frames.build
    @puzzles = Puzzle.all
    @scenes = Scene.all 
end

def create
    puts params.inspect
    @frame = @storyboard.frames.build(frame_params)
    @puzzle = Puzzle.find(frame_params[:puzzle])


    if @frame.save
        flash[:notice] = "Frame has been created."
        redirect_to [@storyboard, @frame]
    else
        flash.now[:alert] = "Frame has not been created."
        render "new"
    end
end

def show

end


private

def set_storyboard
    @storyboard = Storyboard.find(params[:storyboard_id])
end

def frame_params
    params.require(:frame).permit(:frame_order)
end

def set_frame
    @frame = @storyboard.frames.find(params[:id])
end
end
```

It's not complete as I am not trying to locate the scenes yet, I'm trying to
get the puzzle lookup working first.
The params that are showing in WEBrick are as follows:

```
Started POST "/storyboards/2/frames" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-18 
06:33:13 -0500
Processing by FramesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"8KUEIEa7jVS2BsRFby8Cn8Hb0R5LM+paCNbKbfL5ielq01Q7IJlA3HtZX9+pLmYSPhRJq6xlhU2bR7umbv1T+w==", 
"frame"=>{"frame_order"=>"1", "scene"=>"2", "puzzle"=>"1"}, 
"commit"=>"Create Frame", "storyboard_id"=>"2"}
```

My _form.html.erb is as follows:

```
<%= simple_form_for([storyboard, frame]) do |f| %>
<%= f.input :frame_order, label: "Frame Order" %>
<%= f.input :scene, collection: @scenes %>
<%= f.input :puzzle, collection: @puzzles %>

<%= f.button :submit, class: "btn-primary" %>
```

The error that I am getting is as follows:

```
Failure/Error: @puzzle = Puzzle.find(frame_params[:puzzle])

 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
   Couldn't find Puzzle with 'id'=
```

I thought that it might be since I'm using strong params, but if I add
scene and puzzle to the frame_params, I also get an error on the create 
method as follows:

```
Failure/Error: @frame = @storyboard.frames.build(frame_params)

 ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
   Scene(#50941880) expected, got String(#6701160)
```

From what I've been able to lookup, using params[:frame][:puzzle] should work and should give me a value of 1, but instead I'm getting nothing.  I'm not sure what I've done wrong.  Any assistance or advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: where did u created a new instance for story board,in new method first define it.

Answer (score 1):

permit also puzzle in the frame_params like:

`def frame_params
  params.require(:frame).permit(:frame_order,:puzzle)
end`